# Caching in a WCF application

Tags: c#, wcf

The below code throws an error of `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` When calling mycache.Get("products"). Im using a WCF application. Im not 100% im using caching correctly. Any advice?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Web.Caching; 

namespace DataLayer {
    public class Products
    {
        public List<Product> Current()
        {
            Cache mycache = new Cache();
            if (mycache.Get("products")== null)
            {
                using (DataLayer.AccessDataContext db = new AccessDataContext())
                {
                    var products = from p in db.fldt_product_to_supp_parts
                                   where p.Current
                                   select new Product
                               {
                                   WholesaleCode = p.WholesaleCode,
                                   ProductCode = p.Product_Code
                               };
                    mycache["products"] = products.ToList();
                }

            }
            return mycache["products"] as List<Product>;
        }

    } }
```

**EDIT** : I'm using .net 3.5

Comment: I've corrected your title to read "WCF" as per the rest of your question - I hope that's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of the documentation you shouldn't be creating your own instance of the `Cache` class (it says the constructor is for framework use only).  Try using `Cache.Get` instead?

**EDIT** (in response to comment)...

From the MSDN docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it remains valid as long as the application domain remains active. Information about an instance of this class is available through the Cache property of the HttpContext object or the Cache property of the Page object.

So, it looks like `Cache.Get` is available when you're within a Page; otherwise you can call `HttpContext.Cache` to get the active cache.  Either way, there's a single `Cache` object for your entire application and you *definitely* shouldn't be creating one of your own.

Comment: I cant find a static method of Get on cache.

Comment: HttpContext gives the cache for the that one request. Idealy i want to cache the object over the whole application, something like the application cache for aspx sites.

Comment: As per the docs that I quoted: "One instance of this class is created per application domain."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code, because I don't know off-hand how `Cache` is implemented, but a little searching uncovered the following Walkthrough from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997362.aspx

Caching Application Data in a WPF Application

And the following link gives an overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx

In summary, it appears that for .NET v4 onwards, caching has been moved into `System.Runtime.Caching` from `System.Web.Caching`.

Answer (score 0):

For non ASP.NET applications use caching from [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985642.aspx).

Your code throws `System.NullReferenceException` because internal cache `CacheInternal` of `System.Web.Caching.Cache` isn't initialized using `internal void SetCacheInternal(CacheInternal cacheInternal)` method. It initializes by ASP.NET infrastructure in `System.Web.HttpRuntime` class.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you're trying to use the ASP .NET cache within your WCF service. In order for this to work, you need to turn on ASP .NET compatibility using the [AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsmode.aspx). If you're self-hosting you'll have to roll your own.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorSession
{

}
```