# .Net Caching with system.runtime.caching

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am working with .net 4.0 specifically System.runtime.caching.
Has anyone had experience or examples of how to create a custom changemonitor?

What I want to do is, when my program starts it has a execount of 1.  The user clicks a button that increment the execount to 2 and loads db results into cache.  if the execount increments to 3 then i want to invalidate the cache and load new results into cache to use.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

- I have been working on this for a while and came up with this but I don't know if i am on the right track with what I want to do(mentioned above) Primarily because ti is not working correctly.

I have 4 class files

Cache.cs:

```
public static class Cache {

    public static void Add(string key, object obj, CacheItemPolicy policy) {
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        cache.Add(key, obj, policy);
    }

    public static void AddExecCount(string key, object obj) {
        Add(key, obj, new ExecCountCacheItemPolicy());
    }

    public static object Get(string key) {
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        if (cache.Contains(key) == true)
            return cache.Get(key);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static void Clear() {
        Material.MaterialFamilyList.ClearCache();
        Material.UsageMaterialDropList.ClearCache();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the in-memory cache so the list matching the provided key is reloaded on next request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    public static void Clear(string key) {
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        if (cache.Contains(key) == true)
            cache.Remove(key);
    }

}
```

Then ExecCountCacheitemPolicy.cs

```
 public class ExecCountCacheItemPolicy : CacheItemPolicy  {

    public ExecCountCacheItemPolicy() {
        this.ChangeMonitors.Add(new ExecCountChangeMonitor());
        //ExecCount.Increment();
    }

}
```

ExecCountChangeMonitor.cs

```
public class ExecCountChangeMonitor : CacheEntryChangeMonitor {

    private ReadOnlyCollection<String> _cacheKeys;
    private string _uniqueId;
    private string _regionName;
    private DateTimeOffset _lastModified;

    public ExecCountChangeMonitor() {

        _uniqueId = "ExecCountChangeMonitor";
        _regionName = "";
        _lastModified = DateTime.Now;
        var keys = new List<string>();
        keys.Add(ExecCount.CACHE_KEY);
        _cacheKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<String>(keys);

        InitializationComplete();
    }

    public override string UniqueId {
        get { return _uniqueId; }
    }

    public override ReadOnlyCollection<string> CacheKeys {
        get { return _cacheKeys;  }
    }

    public override DateTimeOffset LastModified {
        get { return _lastModified; }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        base.Dispose();
    }

    public override string RegionName {
        get { return _regionName; }
    }


}
```

And finally ExecCount.cs

```
public const string CACHE_KEY = "ExecCount";

    public static int Value { 
        get {
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            if (cache.Contains(CACHE_KEY)) {
                return (int)cache.Get(CACHE_KEY);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int Increment() {

        CacheItem item;
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        if (cache.Contains(CACHE_KEY)) {
            item = cache.GetCacheItem(CACHE_KEY);
        } else {
            item = new CacheItem(CACHE_KEY, 0, "");
            cache.Add(item, new CacheItemPolicy());
        }

        item.Value = (int)item.Value + 1;

        return (int)item.Value;

    }


}
```

If any body has any ides on why this is not working, of if another way could be used to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: This question might hold some useful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664297/caching-in-a-wcf-application/6664440#6664440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CacheEntryChangeMonitor** is used to monitor **other** cache entry, in your way please use `master cache key` to monitor slave.